# kompose failed to convert docker compose for key-only field

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I have a docker-compose.yml file, which is version 2.3. (I had to change to 2 during first try with kompose). 
I tried to convert this yaml file into k8s yaml files with this cmd:

```
kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -v
```

It failed with the error:

```
ERRO Could not parse config for project xxx : Cannot unmarshal '<nil>' to type <nil> into a string value 
FATA composeObject.Parse() failed, Failed to load compose file: Cannot unmarshal '<nil>' to type <nil> into a string value
```

It's apparent that the errors are related to some missing-value fields in the docker-compose.yml file:
e.g.,

```
build:
  context: .
  args:
    http_proxy:
    https_proxy:
    no_proxy:
    socks_proxy:
    TF_ANNOTATION: "no"
```

I searched online and found a related github issue, which seems to have been fixed [Issue388](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/issues/388). (But no). So I'm wondering how to handle the key-only fields during conversion.

My kompose is shipped with the docker desktop on Mac. 
Kompose version: 1.19.0
Docker:

- Engine: 19.03.2
- Compose: 1.24.1
     kubernetes: 1.14.6

Comment: please add the full docker-compose file. does `docker-compose up` work for you?

Comment: @EfratLevitan Yes, docker-compose up works.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the version from 2 to 3 in docker-compose.yml works for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i try to convert a docker-compose.yml with KOMPOSE, but fails.
Solved starting minicube.

```
$ kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml 
$ FATA Unable to load yaml/json file for version parsing: open docker-compose.yml: no such file or directory 

$ minikube start
```

Comment: Do you mean that you worked around the issue, by not using Docker Compose?